# Fastest way to calculate distance

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I have

- a `(n, d)` dimensional matrix `x`
- a `(d, L)` dimensional matrix `c`

Let's denote the b-th row of `x` with `x_b` and the i-th column of `c` with `c_i`. I want to calculate the `(n, L)` dimensional matrix `diff` which contains at `(b, i)`:

```
|| x_b - c_i ||^2,
```

where the bars are the L2-norm.

My current solution uses the trick that

```
|| x - y ||^2 = ||x||^2 + ||y||^2 - 2<x, y>
```

which I calculate like so:

```
# (n, L), contains at (b, i) the inner product <x_b, c_i>
xc = tf.matmul(x, c)

# (n, 1), contains at row b ||x_b||^2
xx = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(x), axis=1, keep_dims=True)

# (1, L), contains at column i ||c_i||^2
cc = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(c), axis=0, keep_dims=True)

# (n, L), contains at (b, i):
# || x_b - c_i ||^2 = ||x_b||^2 + ||c_i||^2 - 2 * <x_b, c_i>
diff = xx + cc - 2*xc
```

It works and is reasonably fast. But I was wondering, is there a trick to make this calculation even faster?

Comment: How slow is it? On my TitanX pascal, I can run your calculation in 0.15 seconds when x and c are 8k by 8k matrices. That's pushing TitanX 11 T ops/sec limit and almost all the time is spent in matmul

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Yeah it's not that slow it's just that I'm running this every iteration as part of neural network training process and every bit of speed results in potential hours saved in training.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov In my setup, n is roughly 300k or more, d is very small, <10 usually, and L is around 1k.

Comment: One potential optimization is that because data is stored in row-major order, reducing over `axis=1` is faster than over `axis=0` because of data locality (ie, 4-5x faster on CPU). Transpose is slow, but maybe you could make sure your `c` is originally stored in transposed order

Comment: and then run as `tf.matmul(x, c, transpose_b=True)` which doesn't do an explicit transpose

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried that, using `transpose_b` in the matmul, switching the axis and then adding a `tf.transpose(cc)` in the last line. Interestingly, it has about equal performance it seems.

Comment: I guess it's an issue of where the time is spent. If most time is spent in matmul, there's not much you can do to improve since `matmul` is well optimized already